# Unable to locate attached view in the native tree

Tags: react-native

When scrolling down and then up a large list of items in a SectionList I receive an error message. I'm wondering if someone else had this problem before, because I wasn't able to find any docs on it.

[image]

Comment: Please copy-paste your code, it would really help people find out what is wrong

Comment: Same problem here. Also handling big chunks of data in state.

Comment: Can you try with a release version? For me it only seems to be happening in debug mode on iOS.

Comment: @Waltari It apprears you are right! I cannot reproduce this issue not in debug! Thanks!!!

Comment: Still not really an answer though :/ I don't recall how to actually get rid of it in debug mode. Probs reset everything or something :D

Comment: Turns out I'm also getting this in android (with debug OFF).

Answer (score 2):

The problem in my case was that I had elements with the same key.
Setting an unique key fixed it.

```
{items.map(item => {
    <Item key={item.uniqueId}/>
})
```

Comment: I am getting this error in my unit test  in AnimatedComponent. I have only one screen

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use Animated Components only

In my case the below line cause this error
I was changing background color with interpolateColor ( react-native-redash)

```
<View style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill, backgroundColor }}></View>
```

correct would be

```
<Animated.View style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFill, backgroundColor }}></Animated.View>
```